# How to assign a task in a task list to a group of team members formed in a custom list?

Tags: list, groups, tasks, contacts

I am using a team site to manage a project.  I made a custom list that shows my project team.  Team members might be individuals or lists of individuals.  For example the title Finance Team Leader is Brian.  But the title Finance Team Committee is Jim, John, and Bob.

When creating tasks I want to be able to assing the task to the title in the custom list that is my project team.  So instead of assigning the task to Jim, John, and Bob, I want to assign the task to "Finance Team Committee".  The problem is that the task assignment box only recognizes groups created in my site permissions, not my other lists.  How to get the assignment box to recognize groups created in my custom project team list?

Comment: Why you haven't used SharePoint Groups instead of Custom List?

Comment: @AmalHashim The list is not just a list.  I create a relational hierarchy that I can latter create a project organization chart out of.  I do use the groups but the groups are more about acccess.  For example I have memebers, and visitors, and owners.  But I rarely want to assign tasks to those groups.  I want to assign tasks according to my project organizational structure which is in my custom list.  Does that make sense?  I feel like it is a logical use of the platform, if I could only assign tasks to the groups in my list.